# jqGrid jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

When I run the following code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/jqGrid/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script src="/jqGrid/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/jqGrid/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

I get the following errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
jQuery is not defined
http://local.wheel/jqGrid/i18n/grid.locale-en.js
Line 128

jQuery is not defined
http://local.wheel/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js
Line 166
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe place the reference to the core jQuery library before the others in your code...

```
<script src="/jqGrid/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/jqGrid/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Order matters here.